# Use CSS to reorder more than one div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a template where the HTML cannot be modified because of other requirements, how is it possible to display (rearrange) a div above another div when they are not in that order in the HTML? Both divs contain data that varies in height and width.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstDiv">
        Content to be below in this situation
    </div>
    <div id="secondDiv">
        Content to be above in this situation
    </div>
</div>
```

Other elements
Hopefully it is obvious that the desired result is:

Content to be above in this situation
Content to be below in this situation
Other elements
When the dimensions are fixed it easy to position them where needed, but I need some ideas for when the content is variable. For the sake of this scenario, please just consider the width to be 100% on both.

Edit: A CSS solution is the most ideal solution. Thank you for the Javascript options mentioned. Without getting too wordy about what or why (or who) ... I am specifically looking for a CSS only solution (and it will probably have to be met with other solutions if that doesn't pan out).

One more ... there are other elements following this. A good suggestion was mentioned given the limited scenario I demonstrated -- given that it might be the best answer, but I am looking to also make sure elements following this aren't impacted.

Comment: if the situations you are referring to are change of widths on different devices then you can use `order` on the divs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also give position relative to id `wrapper`, and give position absolute to all divs inside wrapper, and then setting `top` property of div based on order.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstDiv">
        Content to be below in this situation
    </div>
    <div id="secondDiv">
        Content to be above in this situation
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#firstDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
#secondDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c469kcaz/).

For dynamic height elements, you can use display:table properties.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstDiv">Content to be below in this situation</div>
    <div id="secondDiv">Content to be above in this situation Content to be above in this situation Content to be above in this situation Content to be above in this situation Content to be above in this situation
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
}
#firstDiv {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
#secondDiv {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgc8nboy/4/).

Comment: This is a good solution for fixed height elements but OP needs the solution for variable height elements. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rgc8nboy/

Comment: Good one but we both missed his last paragraph before answering initially. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/ot5t4k7c/1/ My second snippet won't work for his scenario as well. Hope you don't mind my *criticizing* comments :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Check this out, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ot5t4k7c/2/), we can change display based on order. Also check [css stacking](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/06/css/css-stacking-with-display-table). But this limited to only four divs.

Answer (score 6):

With CSS3 flexbox layout module, you can either use `order` or `flex-direction: column-reverse`. Latter will be better if you want the elements to be rearranged in the reverse order(bottom element first, top element last) and avoid playing with the order values. Since you don't want other elements to be affected, go with order solution.

It is worth noting that:

[`order`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) only changes the painting order and not the DOM order.

[`flex-direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property) does not affect painting order but only the direction of flow.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#secondDiv {
  order: -1; /* Negative order because default value is 0 */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="firstDiv">
    Content to be below in this situation
  </div>
  <div id="secondDiv">
    Content to be above in this situation
  </div>
  <div id="thirdDiv">
    Third div unaffected
  </div>
  <div id="fourthDiv">
    Fourth div unaffected
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="firstDiv">
    Content to be below in this situation
  </div>
  <div id="secondDiv">
    Content to be above in this situation
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Marcio Glad that was helpful! :)